# "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class..."

Tags: symfony1

I have downloaded this [PayPal API](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PHP_SO...):

And I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   SOAP_Client in /home/me/app1/
>   plugins/mbpPlatformFrontendPlugin/lib/paypal/PayPal/SOAP/Client.php
>   on line 83

The **strange thing** is: if I change the name of the class to what ever
else, for example *SOAP_Client_foo*, I get

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   SOAP_Client_foo in /home/me/app1/
>   plugins/mbpPlatformFrontendPlugin/lib/paypal/PayPal/SOAP/Client.php
>   on line 83

So I removed the content in Client.php and wrote this:

```
<pre>
<?php
    debug_print_backtrace();
?>
</pre>
<hr />
```

And this is the output:

```
0  require() called at [/home/me/app1/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/
sfAutoload.class.php:188]
1  sfAutoload->loadClass(SOAP_Client) called at [/home/me/app1/lib/
vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfAutoload.class.php: 163]
2  sfAutoload->autoload(SOAP_Client)
4  spl_autoload_call(SOAP_Client) called at [/home/me/app1/plugins/
mbpPlatformFrontendPlugin/lib/paypal/PayPal/CallerServices.php:36]
5  PayPal->getWSDLVersion() called at [/home/me/app1/plugins/
mbpPlatformFrontendPlugin/lib/paypal/PayPal/Profile.php:126]
6  Profile->loadEnvironments() called at [/home/me/app1/plugins/
mbpPlatformFrontendPlugin/lib/paypal/PayPal/Profile.php:104]
7  Profile->_load() called at [/home/me/app1/plugins/
mbpPlatformFrontendPlugin/lib/paypal/PayPal/API.php:328]
8  APIProfile::getInstance(, ProfileHandler_Array...
```

I have typed `.../paypal$ grep -R 'Client.php' *`, and I'm getting this:

```
PayPal/CallerServices.php://require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/Client.php';
PayPal/SOAP/Client.php:// $Id: Client.php,v 1.1.1.1 2006/02/19
PayPal/SOAP/WSDL.php: //require_once 'PayPal/SOAP/Client.php
```

Any help?

sf 1.4

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not consider using: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/prestaPaypalPlugin

It works for Symfony 1.4 :-)

Comment: Thanks, it works ok at least for Checkout Express (I just tried that..).